# How do I solve the overheating issue of my Asus GL702VM gaming laptop?

Tags: cooling, asus-laptop, overheating, laptop-repair, case

My GL702VM has serious overheating issues when under load, specifically graphical.  Looking online I have found this is not a unique issue but a well known design flaw of the case/cooling system that I was not conversant enough with laptop terms/common problems to identify before purchase, and further that claiming warranty is very unlikely to fix the laptop (as it is a design flaw and they don't fix it).

According to Speccy, the laptop heats up to 80-90C and then the performance tanks - even low graphics games stutter and suffer (while reporting high frame rates, despite on-screen seeing lags of 2-3s between things moving).  This issue appears to be getting worse over time.

Various forum posts suggest downvolting the CPU and GPU via a bewildering array of (sometimes now out of date or nonexistent) programs, drilling holes in the case, attaching fans to things, taking apart the laptop and applying thermal gel etc.

I am unsure which of these instructions to follow, my technical skills are relatively limited (I can plug together desktop components inside a regular case, that's about my limit), and the degree to which my laptop is dying seems beyond that which these forum posts describe, so;

- Is there any way to determine/test if the laptop has problems beyond the overheating (perhaps caused by exposure to such excessive heat?), and will asus' standard warranty replace those parts?
- If I need to drill holes in the laptop, is there a visual guide to doing so anywhere?
- Is there any further methods i'm unaware of that can be used to ameliorate this issue?

Comment: My immediate thought would be that this is far too broad to be answered in a few paragraphs - but I'm in a good mood, so I'm not going to vote either way ;) You ought to consider splitting up the problem into smaller, distinct areas, though; even if it takes several successive questions over a few days to get there.

Comment: Heating is a physical issue, and physical solutions are often the most difficult, and if the fail, the most likely to severely damage your computer. Given the content of your question I would tell you not to try any modifications to your computer unless you are prepared to purchase a new one. Get a cooling pad, make sure there is not too much build up on the vents, and don't use the laptop in a hot room.

Comment: Also, if the laptop is under warranty and "normal" computer usage causes it to overheat, that is a hardware issue and should be dealt with under warranty. You should contact warranty support BEFORE you try anything other than getting a cooling pad. Once you've opened the laptop or physically modified it in any way, odds are you've voided your warranty.

Comment: Simplest and easiest might be adding a fan pad underneath, *powered from an external USB adapter ('charger')* rather than from the laptop's USB port (which would add a bit of additional heating). See https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00NNMB3KS/ref=psdc_2243862011_t2_B00FPR8FLY for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar unit GL702vmk here are the stats of my current config.

[ROG panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh7jy.jpg)

[intel XTU config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjCEg.png)

[new option under **Processor power management**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLflt.png)

Throttlestop software can't install on my machine so I opted for editing the registry to add an option to DISABLE the turbo inside **Processor power management**. See 3rd image.
Read from this https://www.geeks3d.com/20170213/how-to-disable-intel-turbo-boost-technology-on-a-notebook/

and this is the link of the regedit file: https://www.geeks3d.com/dl/show/10060

After applying undervolting to -0.135mv and disabling turbo, I was able to reduce CPU temp the usual 89C - 90C down to 75C - 82C.